# Android - Data isn't Being Added to MySQL Database - no errors

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have been working on creating a login/register feature for an app I'm working on (NOTE: this app is for my own personal use right now, so I'm not looking to make my passwords super secure as of now). When I click the register button when running my app on an emulated Android device, Android Studio doesn't throw any errors, but nothing shows up when I check PHP MyAdmin. I've used different username and password combos (the ones here are obviously examples), a bunch of different localhost/127.0.0.1/10.0.2.2 combinations, and nothing seems to be working. When testing it online, 10.0.2.2:8080/android_login_api/register.php says the page cannot be displayed. localhost:8080/android_login_api/register.php at least displays, but with errors saying there is an unknown host (being 10.0.2.2:8080). Also, I am using Port 8080 with WAMP. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

register.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("10.0.2.2:8080" , "EXAMPLE_USERNAME" , "EXAMPLE_PASSWORD" , "android_api");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

RegisterRequest.java:

```
package example.com.musicapptest;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
* Created by Carter Klein on 6/26/2016.
*/
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android_login_api/register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java:

```
package example.com.musicapptest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        final Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        final Button toLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String clickName = name.getText().toString();
                final String clickEmail = email.getText().toString();
                final String clickPassword = password.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean(Integer.parseInt("success"));
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(clickName, clickEmail, clickPassword, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to connect to an invalid mysql host. In the first line of your PHP code the first parameter should be the MySql server address, not the WebServer address.

Comment: So if I am working through localhost would this just be my wireless' IP? The 192.168.x.x? Also if so, would it be 192.168.x.x:8080, or just 192.168.x.x? Thank you!

Comment: If your PHP is running in the same machine of MySql, you can use 127.0.0.1. If they are in different machines you should use the wireless IP.
It should look like:

`$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1" , "EXAMPLE_USERNAME" , "EXAMPLE_PASSWORD" , "android_api");`

or

`$con = mysqli_connect("192.168.x.x" , "EXAMPLE_USERNAME" , "EXAMPLE_PASSWORD" , "android_api");`

Comment: Okay, that worked! BUT, for some reason it is still saying index email is undefined on line 4 (of the php). Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: I guess its because email is not defined when you make the request in RegisterRequest.java.
You only pass name, username and password to the server.